# Generating a nested dictionary in Python through iterations

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested-lists, dictionary-comprehension

I'm new in Python and I have to retrieve datas from a txt file (which I have already did) and then I need to make a nested dictionary like this:

```
new_dict = {"2009-10-16": {"KitchenSensor":"active for x minutes today", 
                              "BathroomSensor":"active for y minutes today"...}
               "2009-10-24":{"KitchenSensor":"active for x minutes today", 
                              "BathroomSensor":"active for y minutes today"...}
                 "2009-11-13":{"KitchenSensor":"active for x minutes today", 
                              "BathroomSensor":"active for y minutes today"...}}
```

my code looks like this

```
namesFile = open("data.txt", "r")  
listaDati = namesFile.readlines()  

listaDivisa = []
for i in listaDati:
    if i[27] != "T":
        listaDivisa.append(
            i.split())
```

and the datas in my txt file have this format:

```
2009-10-16 00:01:04.000059  KITCHENSENSOR ON

2009-10-16 02:33:12.000093  KITCHENSENSOR OFF

2009-10-24 21:25:52.000023  BATHROOMSENSOR ON

2009-10-24 23:13:52.000014  BATHROOMSENSOR OFF

2009-11-13 09:03:23.000053  BATHROOMSENSOR ON

2009-11-13 12:13:42.000014  BATHROOMSENSOR OFF
```

the timestamp changes every now and then so I want to create a new key with the new timestamp everytime I meet a new one and saving the infos I have to save. I was trying doing this with an enumerative for loop but I don't understand how I can create the dictionary.

Thank you!

Comment: please provide all the input data needed to produce the exact provided output

Comment: @mozway the input provided is the string i already put in my question, I have like 200 data sensor, I can't put them all here so I only provided one of them

Comment: I just requested **enough** to generate some relevant input, I guess 6 should be enough? As it is now, **we** would need to generate the data to make your question reproducible. This should be **your** job to do so ;)

Comment: @AriannaCollarile At least add a couple of lines. A single "ON" is not enough. You're also not considering the case where a sensor is turned on during one day and turned off the next (e.g. someone going to the bathroom at 23:58 and leaving at 00:05 the next day).

Comment: @mozway I added them

Comment: Do you want to use pure python or are you open to libraries?

Comment: @AKX oh yep thank you, but i think my tutor will tell me how to handle this specific case. for me now it's a big goal if i can make a nested dictionary!

Comment: @mozway i have to use pure python but if there are more easiest ways to do it with libraries i'm listening

Comment: Well, pandas would help with the dates operations, grouping, speed, etc.

Comment: @AriannaCollarile What is the output of code that you have given for example??

 2009-10-16 00:01:04.000059  KITCHENSENSOR ON

2009-10-16 02:33:12.000093  KITCHENSENSOR OFF

2009-10-24 21:25:52.000023  BATHROOMSENSOR ON

2009-10-24 23:13:52.000014  BATHROOMSENSOR OFF

2009-11-13 09:03:23.000053  BATHROOMSENSOR ON

2009-11-13 12:13:42.000014  BATHROOMSENSOR OFF

Comment: @HiralTalsaniya this strings are the data i'm working on, they are in a .txt file

Comment: @AriannaCollarile but what is output of this ? can you write down it?

Comment: @HiralTalsaniya are you asking what code generates this kind of data? because if this is what you are asking me i don't know, it's a Casas Dataset provided from my uni tutor

Comment: @AriannaCollarile Formate of Output which you want from Above input string?

Comment: @AriannaCollarile YOu want output like thi s??
**{'2009-10-16': {'KITCHENSENSOR': 'ON'}, '2009-10-24': {'BATHROOMSENSOR': 'ON'}, '2009-11-13': {'BATHROOMSENSOR': 'ON'}}**

Comment: @HiralTalsaniya oh yes i want this kind of output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're maybe looking for something like this; I separated the task into

1. parsing the input lines (could be from a file, but here they're just a list) into events (3-tuples of datetime, sensor name and state)
2. grouping the events by date, and looking at the state changes.

```
import datetime
from itertools import groupby


def parse_line(line):
    # Split the line at the two spaces.
    time_string, event = line.split("  ", 1)
    # Split the rest of the line at one space.
    sensor, event = event.split(" ", 1)
    # Parse the time string to a real datetime object.
    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    return (t, sensor, event == "ON")


def collate_sorted_events(sorted_events):
    zero_delta = datetime.timedelta(0)
    for day, events in groupby(
        sorted_events, lambda event_triple: event_triple[0].date()
    ):
        # We're assuming all sensors start off each day.
        turn_on_times = {}
        durations = {}
        for time, sensor, state in events:
            if state:  # Turning on?
                # If it was on already, that's not an issue; we just consider that a glitch.
                if sensor not in turn_on_times:
                    turn_on_times[sensor] = time
            else:
                if sensor not in turn_on_times:
                    raise ValueError("Sensor was turned off before it was turned on.")
                this_duration = time - turn_on_times[sensor]
                durations[sensor] = durations.get(sensor, zero_delta) + this_duration
                del turn_on_times[sensor]
        yield (day, durations)
        if turn_on_times:
            # This check could be removed, but for now it's a good sanity check...
            raise ValueError(
                "Some sensors were left on at the end of the day; this could be a problem"
            )


listaDati = [
    "2009-10-16 00:01:04.000059  KITCHENSENSOR ON",
    "2009-10-16 02:33:12.000093  KITCHENSENSOR OFF",
    "2009-10-24 21:25:52.000023  BATHROOMSENSOR ON",
    "2009-10-24 23:13:52.000014  BATHROOMSENSOR OFF",
    "2009-11-13 09:03:23.000053  BATHROOMSENSOR ON",
    "2009-11-13 12:13:42.000014  BATHROOMSENSOR OFF",
]

# Parse and sort input lines.  It's imperative that the events are sorted
# so the rest of the code works as it should.
sorted_events = sorted(parse_line(i) for i in listaDati)

# Collate events by day; the function yields day/durations tuples,
# and `dict` accepts that format to create a dict with.
output = dict(collate_sorted_events(sorted_events))
print(output)
for date, deltas in sorted(output.items()):
    for sensor, delta in sorted(deltas.items()):
        print(f"{date} {sensor} {delta.total_seconds() / 60:.2f} minutes")
```

The output is

```
{
  datetime.date(2009, 10, 16): {'KITCHENSENSOR': datetime.timedelta(seconds=9128, microseconds=34)},
  datetime.date(2009, 10, 24): {'BATHROOMSENSOR': datetime.timedelta(seconds=6479, microseconds=999991)},
  datetime.date(2009, 11, 13): {'BATHROOMSENSOR': datetime.timedelta(seconds=11418, microseconds=999961)},
}
```

followed by the formatted

```
2009-10-16 KITCHENSENSOR 152.13 minutes
2009-10-24 BATHROOMSENSOR 108.00 minutes
2009-11-13 BATHROOMSENSOR 190.32 minutes
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 48, in <module>
    sorted_events = sorted(parse_line(i) for i in listaDati)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 48, in <genexpr>
    sorted_events = sorted(parse_line(i) for i in listaDati)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 11, in parse_line
    time_string, event = line.split("  ", 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Well, that means not all of the lines in your file are in the format you told us they'd be in. You will have to adapt the code so it works with your data. I'd guess that might be a blank line, for instance.

Comment: ok I will check up because it's a big dataset provided by my uni tutor so i don't know everything that's wrote there, thank you so much tho, i appreciate that!